# Using Wordpress for a site's static marketing pages and blog at different URLs

Tags: urls

Noob question.

I would like to use Wordpress such that a single installation can support pages and blog posts at different URLs. I have a site built, and we want to use Wordpress for both marketing landing pages and blog pages. Examples:

Marketing "static pages" live at the root URL (and are set via Wordpress CMS as 'pages'):

- ht_tp://website.com/faq
- ht_tp://website.com/story
- ht_tp://website.com/wizard-sauce

However, the blog lives at the blog URL:

- ht_tp://website.com/blog/post-1
  etc. etc.

Any clues on how to best accomplish? Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple and can be accomplished all through the admin interface.

First, create pages named Home and Blog under Pages.

Then go to Settings > Reading, and under Front page displays, set Front page to your Home page, and Posts page to your Blog page.

Next, under Settings > Permalinks, Select Custom Structure and enter `/blog/%postname%/`.

If you also want category and tag permalinks to contain `blog`, you can set those to `blog/category` and `blog/tag`.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to use multiple sites under my own Wordpress installation I would use the multisite features of Wordpress. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: I would definitely recommend *against* using multisite for something so simple.